# Get the pivot on the property name and list the property value

Tags: c#, json, json.net, pivot, pivot-table

Given this data in JSON:

```
[
        {
                "section": "charges",
                "lines": [
                        {
                                "cardtype": "MasterCard"
                        },
                        {
                                "sales": "$16.55"
                        },
                        {
                                "items": "10"
                        },
                        {
                                "cardtype": "Visa"
                        },
                        {
                                "sales": "$16.50"
                        },
                        {
                                "items": "39"
                        },
                        {
                                "cardtype": "Diners"
                        },
                        {
                                "sales": "40.00"
                        },
                        {
                                "items": "10"
                        }
                ]
        }
]
```

I'd like to pivot on the property name and list the property value -- perhaps in a DataTable?

The data is collected as a `Dictionary<string,object>()`

I need to aggregate the sales and item counts by cardtype. e.g.:

`+---------------+-------+-------+
| cardtype      | sales | items |
+---------------+-------+-------+
| Mastercard    | 16.55 | 10    |
| Visa          | 16.50 | 39    |
| Diners        | 40.00 | 10    |
+---------------+-------+-------+
| Total         | 73.05 | 59    | <- would be calculated after conversion.`
+---------------+-------+-------+

I've tested `SelectTokens()` method and I can pull up the array of lines, but pivoting is proving difficult because field names will be different depending on where the data is sourced.

Any Ideas?

Comment: code trials please

Comment: `JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json); jo.SelectToken("lines[0]")` would return only the first record and value as a JObject and JProperty I was trying to iterate all of the properties and add them to new IDictionary

Comment: Here is some more code `var r = jo.SelectToken("lines");
 foreach( JToken item in r ) {
  foreach(JProperty prop in item ) {
  Console.WriteLine(item[prop.Name]);
 }
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the below code

```
var files = JArray.Parse(JSON);
var recList = files.SelectToken("$..lines");
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recList);
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(\{[^}]+)\},\{([^}]+)\},\{([^}]+)\}");
var output = regex.Replace(str, "$1, $2, $3 }");
System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, (typeof(System.Data.DataTable)));
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tested this and the problem is I get a bunch of nulls because each element is a token. I get jagged data in the data table.

Comment: Updated answer, I think thats because of the extra braces we have on json

Comment: probably need a regex for removing those extra braces

Comment: Right -- this is the problem. The "Mastercard" "$16.55" and "10" must be on one line. Thats the challenge.

Comment: Good for use of Regex. Interesting solution!

Comment: one minor correction -- should be de-serializing "output" not "str" but it seems to work.